# how to know which time period you are on similar to isdaily, isweekly?

Tags: pine-script

i want to set a variable depended to what time frame we are at

like this:

```
 a = 0
//if it was 5m time frame a=1
//if it was 15m time frame a=2
//if it was 45m time frame a=3
//if it was 60 time frame a=4

a = is5mTimePeriod ? 1 : is15mTimeperiod ? 2 : .............
```

I know the conditional operators and just want to know the function that allows me to get the time frame instead my fake functions that I wrote above : is5mTimePeriod , is15mTimeperiod.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "period" built-in variable.  Here's a link to the documentation: [Pine Script Language Reference](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#var_period)

Comment: Thank you, I had the same question.

Answer (score 0):

```
chartResolution = interval
if isdaily 
    chartResolution := 24*60*interval
if isweekly 
    chartResolution := 24*60*7*interval
if ismonthly 
    chartResolution := 24*60*30*interval
```

This portion of code will give you the number of minutes of a single bar (approx. for monthly), no matter the chosen period of the chart, including the personalized ones.

Hope it helps